# Is it possible to $_GET without an ID?

Tags: php, html

I have a number of pages that use `$_GET` but there is only ever 1 ID.

For example `/view/document/id=1` so I use `$_GET['id']` which is 1.

Is it possible to do `/view/document/1` and if so what would the `$_GET` be?

I did try searching online but all I could find was information on sessions for some reason!

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Answer (score 3):

You would use GET the same way, but you'll have to modify routing to match the url... See tutorials to get an idea, because it's a kinda broader topic, for instance here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049
[Routing php query using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021346/routing-php-query-using-htaccess)

Etc. Just search for `url routing` or `url rewriting` if these links ever stop being available.

You'll just have to specify few rewrite rules and you're good to go.

If you use some framework later, these tend to do some stuff for you, but you'll have to specify some rules for routing anyway, so it's a good idea to understand the basics with .htaccess first.

Answer (score 1):

if you use mvc frameworks like codeigniter or cakephp or yii then its possible easily.
on the other hand you can try with .htaccess, I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [.htaccess rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). With that you can change the displayed URL without changing the `$_GET['id']`